# fading-in every word of a paragraph in different random time effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I am trying to fade-in every word of a paragraph with random speed, so that it creates an effect of words appearing on paper. I am using jquery and doing it in this way. but this seams quite heavy (is it so?).
  please suggest a better way to do so.

```js
$('body').children('.word').each(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 500);
});
```

```css
.word {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="word">
  hello,
</div>
<div class="word">
  how
</div>
<div class="word">
  are
</div>
<div class="word">
  you
</div>
<div class="word">
  doing
</div>
```

Comment: May be it's better idea to use css transitions?

Comment: sorry i am very new to css transitions. Can you please give me some hint. on how can i do this.

Comment: I posted solution in answer. hope it will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using css transitions

JS:

```
$('body').children('.word').each(function() {
    var word = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(word).css("opacity", 1);
    }, Math.random() * 3000)
});
```

CSS:

```
.word {
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n427mLb8/

You could eliminate using wrappers around each word using javascript like that:

```
$('.content').html($('.content').text().split(/[\s,\.]+/).map(function (word) {
    return '<div class="word">' + word + '</div>'
}).join(''))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6e948j26/

Comment: Thanks but can i have the fading-in effect as well,i mean is there a way to animate opacity with css?

Comment: At least can i do something that'll save me surrounding every word with a div tag??

Comment: there is no way how to select individual words without wrapping them with html element... but you can make wrappers in your js. I showed example in my answer